# Class nrc2 Warning: GUTenberg Babel french style detected -- (nrc2) some corruption of NRC-defined format may occur

Tags: documentclass

Writing a paper for NRC research press. I am dealing with many problems! I think the reason that nothing works smoothly for me is the errors I get at the beginning of writing the paper.
These are the two errors I get right of the bat:

1. Class nrc2 Warning: GUTenberg Babel french style detected -- (nrc2) some corruption of NRC-defined format may occur.
2. Class nrc2 Warning: One of abstract and resume missing on input line 37.

This is what I have:

```
\documentclass[]{nrc2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\journalcode{cgj}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.95}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A1}
\address[ad]{Adrress}
\author{A2}
\author{A3}
\correspond{email}

\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The first warnings mean that the class must be adapted to newer tex systems. It won't work currently with a current babel-french as it makes assumptions that are no longer valid. If you are writing only in english, you could load only  `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. The second warning means that you are missing the required resume environment.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is annoying, but innocuous, unless you need to use French.

There used to be two conflicting versions of French support for `babel`; one was made by Bernard Gaulle and `nrc2` identifies it with “GUTenberg Babel” (which is not correct); it was not entirely compatible with other `babel` modules and `nrc2` decided to warn about this by just checking for the presence in the system of the file `french.ldf`.

This is a mistake: the fact that the file is present doesn't mean the document is actively using it. On the other hand, that file was not included in TeX Live for licensing reasons, so for the majority of users in the world (excluding the French), the check could make some sense (not much, I'd say). To add to the confusion, that package *was* included in TeX Live because licensing restrictions were lifted off.

Since 2017, `babel-french` uses `french.ldf` as the main file for French localization (it's possible to use Gaulle's extensions in a different way) and so *everybody* has `french.ldf` on their system.

Don't worry and possibly silence the warning:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{nrc2}{GUTenberg}

\documentclass[]{nrc2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\journalcode{cgj}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.95}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A1}
\address[ad]{Adrress}
\author{A2}
\author{A3}
\correspond{email}

\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If you need French, you need a couple of other fixes:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{nrc2}{GUTenberg}
\WarningFilter{french.ldf}{Figures'}
\WarningFilter{french.ldf}{OT1}

\documentclass[]{nrc2}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\NRC@french@lang{frenchb}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\journalcode{cgj}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.95}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{A1}
\address[ad]{Adrress}
\author{A2}
\author{A3}
\correspond{email}

\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Don't load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, because the class only supports OT1.

For the second warning, check the `nrc2` class documentation.

Comment: The warning is harmless as long as one doesn't load babel, but if one add  -- as suggested by the docu -- `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}` one get a runaway argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added the relevant fix.